# How to retrieve data from MYSQL database using checkboxes in PHP and how to set an if statement to give you an specific result by comparing?

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Before I start on this things and I would like to inform that I have tried to find in the web, youtube and books and it seems I don't get a clue for what I am exactly trying to do.

The main feature of this page is the following as example:
a `MySQL` database in `XAMPP` and a `HTML` page with `PHP` on it.
My `PHP` code conects to the `DB` and then I have created 3 checkboxes -

- 1 - MOUSE
- 2 - Dog
- 3 - Tiger

( This things will be the checkboxes options. with an input button (to retrieve the info)

If you select checkbox 1 the `PHP` code should call the `Table` animals and give you as result MOUSE

But I want that if user select Mouse and DOG, retrieve the fastest animal in this case will be Checkbox 2:
Or if user select 3 of them gives you as result number 3 (Tiger.)

I being watching tutorials and so on an the retrieve I got it but only for the HTML part even I can connect to the DB, the questions will be

How do I set first the Checkboxes?
How do I call the database to each of this checkboxes?
Which comparison statement do I need to use in order to give me the desired logic?

```html
html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Fastest animal selection</title> 
      </head>  
      <body>  
        <div class="container box">
          <h3 align="center">Fastest animal selection</h3><br />
          <h4>Please Select your Animal.</h4><br />  
          <form method="post">
           <p><input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="MOUSE" /> MOUSE</p>
           <p><input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="DOG" /> DOG</p>
           <p><input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="TIGER" /> TIGER</p>
           <p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Get fastest animal" /></p>
          </form>
          <?php
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
          {
           $for_query = '';
           if(!empty($_POST["animal"]))
           {
            foreach($_POST["animal"] as $animal)
            {
             echo '<p>'.$animal.'</P>';
    }
    }
    else
    { 
   echo "<label class='text-danger'>* Please select at least one animal.</label>";
   }
   }
   ?>
   </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: right, so whats the problem? You haven't included any SQL code in this

Comment: Im not really sure how the code will be.

Comment: I could create a Primery Key like "Animal_ID" and with that call this id from the Table "Animals" can you give a clue? regards.